# If $f$ is differentiable in $B(a)$ , so $\nabla f=0 \implies f=\text{constant}$ and $f(x)\leq f(a) \implies \nabla f(a)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Assume $f: U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at each point of an $n-$ball $B(a)$. Prove that

1. $\forall x \in B(a): \quad \nabla f(x)=0 \implies f$ is constant function in $B(a)$.
2. $\forall x \in B(a): f(x)\leq f(a) \implies $ $\nabla f(a)=0$.

How Can I prove it?

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

1. We can see that $$\nabla f(x)=0 \implies \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}: \quad \partial_{i}f(x)=0$$Then all the coordinate functions are constant on $B(a)$. So, $f$ is constant on $B(a)$.
2. I haven't idea.

Comment: Let $e_j$ be the $j$th unit vector. Then $f(a) \geq f(x)$ implies that $f(a+he_j) - f(a) / h \leq 0$ when $h \to 0$ from the negative side and $f(a+he_j) - f(a) / h \geq 0$ when $h\to 0$ from the positive side. Combining these two facts implies that $D_jf(a) = 0$ for $j = 1,...,n$

Comment: Coordinate functions?